# How to update and use an object in main() from another thread class in java

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist, collections, thread-safety

users are not getting appended to the ArrayList and only prints only one element which is inserted by that thread. What changes have to be made here?

I have tried using synchronized(users) but still wont work.

```
/*This is the main Class from which threads are created*/
public class MultiThread {

    List<String> users = Collections.synchronizedList(new  ArrayList<String>());
    public static MyThread[] threads=new MyThread[10];
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
       while(true){
          for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
             if(threads[i]==null){
                        (threads[i] = new MyThread().start();
                        break;
             }
          }
       }
    }

    /*Adding names to Arraylist */

    public synchronized void adduser(String user){
       users.add(user);
    }
    /*print Array elements */
    public void iter(){
       Iterator<String> foreach = users.iterator();
       while (foreach.hasNext()) System.out.println(foreach.next());
    }
}

class MyThread extends Thread {

    private BufferedReader in=null;
    public void run(){
        MultiThread obj=new MultiThread();
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader());
        System.out.println("Enter you name");
        name=in.readLine();
        obj.adduser(name);
        System.out.println("Current Users are:");
        obj.iter();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the same `MultiThread` object to all of your threads. All the threads are creating new instances of `MultiThread` objects.